# Approval process request

Tags: approval-process

How to send the approval request to an email field?

Requirement is:
 When the criteria meets, an approval email will be send to the email field not any user, group or related user.

Comment: So who will be the approver of the request?

Comment: The approver should be the email field

Comment: I am afraid that's not possible. Approver will have to be an User. What is your requirement in bigger picture, may be we will be able to give you some alternative. Update your question please.

Comment: On Leave request object when an employee will create a record then an approval mail will be sent to its manager. To get manger's email I am updating manager's email Id in a manager email field on leave request object

Comment: The manager is an user of the system, right? And you are capturing the manager's email in the Leave Request object? Why not in the Users' standard Manager field?

Answer (score 1):

You can only send approval request to User, Partner User, Customer Portal User or Related User.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a new field called "Initial Submitter" on the object for which the approval process exists.
2.Create a Field Update that updates the field "Initial Submitter" to "$User.Email" (the current user's email address).

3.Navigate to the approval process, and add a new Initial Submission Action, and select the field update that was just created above.

4.From here on, you can create a new Email Alert, and the Recipient Type field, you will select Email Field->Initial Submitter.

Comment: Want this field as an "Assigned Approver"